# Django Social Auth check if user is new in view

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using django-social-auth by @Omab for my site.

In the settings, I have `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL` set to, say, `/profile`. My question is, in the view, how do I check if the user is new? Is there a variable that I can access?

Comment: What do you mean if the user is new? Or you want to check if the user is trying to login by very first time after they have signup?

Comment: If you want to check is user is logged in or not you might want to user something like `request.user.is_authenticated()` is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am not looking to see if the user is logged in. I just wanted to see if the user who is accessing the `/profile` page is a new user or is a returning user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The variable `is_new` is set in the `request.session` variable. You can access it as follows:

```
name = setting('SOCIAL_AUTH_PARTIAL_PIPELINE_KEY', 'partial_pipeline')
if name in request.session:
    if request.session[name]['kwargs']['is_new'] == True:
        #Do something.
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: That will work only on partial-pipelines. The purpose of `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL` is to define a destination for new, and only new, users, so I would suggest using a query parameter or a new URL like @krak3n suggested below. Also the app is open to pull-requests and adding the `is_new` flag to the session is easy, but should be cleaned after by some of your views otherwise the user will be flagged as new all the time.

Comment: @omab: You're right. I was using a partial-pipeline and thus found this solution convenient. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL` both point to `/profile`. And you want to deferenciate between users being directed to `/profile` who where sent there using `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL`.

The simplest way to do this would be to have a new url pattern like this:

#### urls.py

```
urls = [
    (r'^profile/$', 'profile'),
    (r'^profile/new/$', 'profile', {'new_user': True}),
]

urlpatterns = patterns('project.app.views', *urls)
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def profile(request, new_user=False):
    if new:
         # if user is new code
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', {'new_user': new_user})
```

#### settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/new'
```

Read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions

:)

Comment: Hey, thanks. What you've said is one way to do it. The Social Auth plugin has a variable for this, and that is what I was looking for. Found it finally; I've added an answer, please check it out.